# angular mongodb array format is written wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to write the following to my db that has a field 'items':

```
$scope.variable = [[1,2],[3,4]];
```

value of items =  1,2,3,4 instead of [1,2],[3,4]

When I write it as `angular.toJson($scope.variable)` it does get separated, but how do I ng-repeat it as 1,2 and 3,4 instead of [[1,2],[3,4]]

This doesn't work :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in dbValues"><td>{{x.items}}</td></tr>
```

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="item in x"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>

Comment: it should not be `{{x.items}}`, it would be `{{x}}` only

Comment: I edited question so to make it easier to understand

Comment: @brucelee did you checked my answer? Does i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting populated two dimentional array on html you need to do ng-repeat twice

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
  <td ng-repeat="subItem in item">{{subItem}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssanZG9iXyGKls4ds09K?p=preview) here

**Update**

For json like `{ "_id" : ObjectId("550ec51fd8b9bff112000006"), "items" : "[[\"a\"],[\"a\",\"b\"]]", "__v" : 0 }`

You need items array from it, and inside that items are contained in dimentional array, basically you need to flatten that array. And it can be easily possible using angular custom filter

**Filter**

```
.filter('flattenarray', function(){
  return function(valuesString){
    var jsonValues = angular.fromJson(valuesString), returnValue = [];
    angular.forEach(jsonValues, function(value, index){
      angular.forEach(value, function(v, i){
        returnValue.push(v);
      });
    });
    return returnValue;
  }
});
```

Then use this filter on markup to flatten items object

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
  <td ng-repeat="subItem in item.items | flattenarray track by $index">{{subItem}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yo2ig3EQPM0WhCLTxNNN?p=preview)

Comment: It's not working :(
I did this now:
`<tr ng-repeat="x in dbValue track by $index"><td><span ng-repeat="content in x.items track by $index">{{content}}</span></td></tr>`

Comment: Does `x`(each object) contains `items` object? I think `x.items` should be only `x`, your code should be `<tr ng-repeat="x in dbValue track by $index"><td><span ng-repeat="content in x track by $index">{{content}}</span></td></tr>`

Comment: yes it contains item object. result is [[1,2],[3,4]]

if I do content in x I jus get more stuff like the id etc. the .items part contains the [[1,2],[3,4]] value

Comment: could you please provide me the whole json? I'm not able to get whole picture what you are talking..

Comment: in mongo: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("550ec51fd8b9bff112000006"), "items" : "[[\"a\"],[\"a\",\"b\"]]", "__v" : 0 }
`
in controller: `$scope.dbValue = angular.fromJson(data);`

Comment: thank you very much man. Is this is recommended way for doing it, or should I have written the data into my database in a different/better way?

Comment: I believe this would be a better way..Do filtering on client side, if it does help you then do upvote/mark as correct, Thanks :)

Comment: thank you very much, much appreciated for your time and effort thanks man